# Getting Same Description in All the Custom Taxonomy Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-development, custom-post-type-archives

I have developed a custom taxonomy post type. I have displayed categories & inside categories posts/(products).

I am getting the Post title & Image as they should be (which I add), but the descriptions of all the posts are same.

I have no idea why same desc keeps displaying,even though everything else is dynamic.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$taxID = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'industrial_product',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'industrial_product_cat',
            'terms' => $taxID,
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    ),
  );
     $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()):
        $i=1;
    foreach( $query->posts as $id ):?>
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
                    <?php
                    $image_palette = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $id ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
                    ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image_palette[0]; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:100%;">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-12">
                     <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item m-0" role="presentation">
                            <a class="nav-link active  c-2" id="productInfo<?php echo $i;?>-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#productInfo<?php echo $i;?>" role="tab" aria-controls="productInfo<?php echo $i;?>" aria-selected="true">Product Information</a>
                         </li>
                        <li class="nav-item m-0" role="presentation">
                            <a class="nav-link  c-2" id="std_tds<?php echo $i;?>-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#std_tds<?php echo $i;?>" role="tab" aria-controls="std_tds<?php echo $i;?>" aria-selected="false">STD / TDS</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content p-3" id="myTabContent<?php echo $i;?>">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="productInfo<?php echo $i;?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="productInfo<?php echo $i;?>-tab">
                            <h5><?php echo get_the_title($id); ?></h5>
                            <p><?php echo get_the_content($id); ?></p>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="std_tds<?php echo $i;?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="std_tds<?php echo $i;?>-tab">
                        <?php
                                if(get_field('std_tds_description', $id)){
                                    the_field('std_tds_description',  $id);
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo "No, Content.";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $i++;
    endforeach;
    endif;
//              
            }
             
    ?>
```

**Here is a screenshot of the result:**

[image]

Can somebody point out what is the problem here. I've tried all sort of stuff but It still shows same desc.
Thanks & Sorry If I'm doing something stupid, still learning!

Comment: Did you use ACF?  `get_field()` looks like an ACF thing.  If that's the case I'd check with their developers and documentation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Yes I am using advanced custom fields. Let me try & ask them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the call

**Old:** **`<?php echo get_the_content( $id ); ?>`**

**New:** **`echo get_post_field('post_content', $id);`**

Don't know what was wrong but, It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The correct WordPress loop structure is:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Does this code is working ?

```
    $taxID = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $args  = array(
        'post_type'      => 'industrial_product',
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'industrial_product_cat',
                'terms'    => $taxID,
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ):
        $i = 1;
        while ( $query->have_posts() ):
            $query->the_post();
            $id = get_the_ID();
            ?>
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
                    <?php
                    $image_palette = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $id ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image_palette[0]; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid" style="max-width:100%;">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-12">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item m-0" role="presentation">
                            <a class="nav-link active  c-2" id="productInfo<?php echo $i; ?>-tab" data-toggle="tab"
                               href="#productInfo<?php echo $i; ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="productInfo<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-selected="true">Product
                                Information</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item m-0" role="presentation">
                            <a class="nav-link  c-2" id="std_tds<?php echo $i; ?>-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#std_tds<?php echo $i; ?>" role="tab"
                               aria-controls="std_tds<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-selected="false">STD / TDS</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content p-3" id="myTabContent<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="productInfo<?php echo $i; ?>" role="tabpanel"
                             aria-labelledby="productInfo<?php echo $i; ?>-tab">
                            <h5><?php echo get_the_title( $id ); ?></h5>
                            <p><?php echo get_the_content( $id ); ?></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="std_tds<?php echo $i; ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="std_tds<?php echo $i; ?>-tab">
                            <?php
                            if ( get_field( 'std_tds_description', $id ) ) {
                                the_field( 'std_tds_description', $id );
                            } else {
                                echo "No, Content.";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            $i ++;
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Yes I've also shared screenshot of the result. Its working fine, just the descriptions is same for every post